# almost certainly a mysql bug?

Tags: mysql

```
mysql> select id,id_product,date_start from prices where date_start >= '2014-05-01 00:00:00.000' and id_product=21 and id_cr=2733 order by id limit 1;
| 660713 | 21 | 2014-05-01 01:00:00 |

mysql> select id,id_product,date_start,date_end from prices where date_start >= '2014-05-01 00:00:00.000' and id_product=21 and id_cr=2733 order by id limit 1;
| 660712 | 21 | 2014-05-01 00:00:00 | 2014-05-01 01:00:00 |
```

So, the simple fact that I added a new field to the second SELECT (date_end) changed the result of my query (and I can guarantee my database wasn't being modified at the same time... I also actually rerun those same commands a couple times and this happened everytime).

There's something else funny.

If I use "select * ... limit 8", I get 8 records starting from 660713

If I use "select * ... limit 7", I get 7 records starting from 660712 (which is correct), since 660712 matches this query

So, any ideas what's going on with record 660712?!

I'm guessing some indexes problem

thanks!

Comment: I agree with index problem. Try check the query execution plan of each SQL using `EXPLAIN`. Disagree with mysql bug..

Comment: Are you able to reproduce this error? See if you can create a [self contained example](http://www.sscce.org/) of it, perhaps using http://sqlfiddle.com ?

Comment: are you sure that the two queries are identical (apart for the `date_end` column)?

Comment: this is similar I guess:
"select id from prices where id_cr=2733 and date_start >= '2014-05-01 00:00:00' and id_product = 21 limit 1;" returns id 660712... if I add ".0" to the date (milliseconds), then it returns 660713... if I keep the ".0" but change the >= to =, it returns 660712

Comment: if I remove the "and id_product=21" (all records have id_product=21 anyway) it returns 660712 for all the queries I said

Comment: using "explain" I noticed that when I have the "and id_product" the key_len jumps from 4 to 12... so it really seems to be something related to indexes... i just don't know what do check... and I didn't manage to make a self-contained example yet